# Recovering Word file from Encrypted External HDD

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, microsoft-word-2010, hard-drive-recovery

My partner is a teacher and therefore requires her external hard drive to be formatted using encryption called Endpoint. She had been writing reports and lost them. I have tried via Remote Assistance to help her but I am coming up stuck, so anyone that can offer suggestions would be a hero tonight.

The file was originally on the Hard drive and saved there. 
It was then Extracted to the desktop on her Laptop. 
She has then opened the file on the laptop only to find it is an old version.
The file on the Hard drive is not there now.

I have no idea how exactly she has done this and what steps she followed to reach this outcome, and she cannot tell me precisely what she did. I find it strange how the extracted file has gone back to an old version.

The Word document was only worked on using the laptop (as opposed to on another machine) and the final, complete version was definitely saved on the hard drive.

She is running Windows 10 with Word 2010.

Word has AutoRecover enabled but there was nothing in the folder. 
There was no option for document recovery upon re-opening Word.

The version on the desktop is listed as being 'created' tonight - suggesting that this version is simply a copy of the original, hence why I can find no previous versions or history.

I have searched the folder on the hard drive but cannot see the file. She is certain she did not delete it.

Can someone offer any suggestions as to where I could search to find an extracted file on an encrypted hard drive? Would the hard drive store the AutoRecovery or previous versions somewhere unexpected (i.e. on the hard drive as opposed to the laptop?).

I have never used this encryption software so don't know what influence this is having on the missed file but my partner is stressed out and hopefully we can get a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Normal file recovery would use an undelete-type program, or a data carving program, but encryption is an extra layer of confusion. Is it an entire encrypted drive like TrueCrypt or LUKS, once you login it "looks" like a regular drive you can search? If so, then an undelete or carving program might work (if the files weren't overwritten).

Comment: Hi Xen, thank you for your response. Yes, you are right about the extra confusion. No, the drive does not behave like a regular drive, double-clicking on the drive opens a new window where you login and view the files something similar to 7-Zip or WinRAR, where you have options to extract, etc. It's like its own piece of software.

Comment: You can try using file recovery software on the encrypted drive, provided Endpoint mounts the drive in a way, where the entire drive is readable.  If that is not the case, then you are out of luck, the file cannot be recovered since the data on the HDD is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

If only the external hard drive was encrypted, maybe the file is still on one of the internal/regular hard drives on one of the computers, either desktop or laptop. Or it may be recoverable there (undelete, search all free space, etc).

That encryption sounds like it keeps files locked in an archive, so every time you want to use it to extract a file to an internal/local hard drive (as opposed to TrueCrypt/LUKS that only decrypts in ram "on-the-fly"), maybe the file exists a few places yet, temporary files or in now free space?

Searching for every existing word document on the drive might find it hiding somewhere, Windows' *should* have a search/find that *should* work.

I'd try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to look for deleted files, in case it's still easily recoverable. Or [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to search all the free space on the drive and only look for Word / MS Office documents

For the future, remember ***backups*** on a separate drive or online (if the school doesn't object). Actually, it may be possible that the school has an automatic online backup of their encrypted hard drives, that would be fortunate, tried asking them? They might even have some ideas on recovery on the encrypted external drive.